# Can SOA and Microservices co-exist?

Tags: architecture, soa, microservices

It is often documented to build a microservice based architecture from a monolith. Is it also possible to have microservices in SOA based architecture?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can absolutely have both architectures in the same environment. Here is why:

Microservices Architecture is heavily inspired by SOA, so naturally principles used in both are very similar and there's often confusion between both. However, you should note that **these paradigms differ in scope**. **Microservices Architecture** is an approach to design an application in a specific way, while **SOA** aims to put order in communication between multiple heterogeneous applications (often in enterprise environment) in different domains, avoid point-to-point communication by having a middleware in place and generally reduce integration effort and increase ROI in the long term. SOA is not just an architectural approach but offers a whole new approach to optimize the IT domain in an enterprise. It often requires changes to processes and hierarchy, because a SOA governance body would need to be in place at some point to ideally enforce enterprise policies.

So in practice you'll very often see something like this - many application architecture styles in the same general SOA:

[image: many application architecture styles in the same general SOA]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Basically, we can say if you are interacting any external service or application from your microservice based application, Better to use ESB, If transportation protocols are different. Otherwise, use API gateway, if integration system/service are using homogeneous protocols.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms Microservices is subset of SOA. You can refer to the following [9 characteristics of Microservice](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html), they still do follow SOA design principles:

Componentization via Services

Organized around Business Capabilities

Products not Projects

Smart endpoints and dumb pipes

Decentralized Governance

Decentralized Data Management

Infrastructure Automation

Design for failure

Evolutionary Design

If you are referring SOA architecture implementing ESB, then using ESB does not necessarily makes you SOA compliant, unless you adhere to Service characteristics/service design principles of service during service design & modelling. Hence lets decouple Services & ESB. Fundamentally ESB is just an implementation of few non-functional elements of SOA.

Choosing a monolith application is a fundamental phenomenon to start with Microservices. However I strongly believe Microservices can be taken to much more business scenarios.

Comment: I agree usage of ESB alone doesn't quality for a good SOA design. However, it is almost unanimously said ESB is not used in MSA. If Not, why and in that case, which component/layer in MSA can handle xformation/protocol translation etc?

Comment: In MSA we follow "Smart endpoints and dumb pipes" which says that transformation/protocol translation is the respective service responsibility. In other words transformation/translation could also act as a re-usable utility service. Though MSA does not recommend ESB, at the same time it does not mandate to remove ESB. Under logical and tight coupling situations which creates the dependency of ESB with your enterprise systems, you could always consider ESB as part of your MSA.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people relate to Microservices as SOA 2.0, so If I get your question correctly, you definitely can use both architectures in one project...

Comment: ESB in SOA is used to perform protocol translation/ req-resp transformation as required. As microservices is often perceived as Smart Endpoint-Dumb Pipes, where in microservices architecture we can handle these cases? Netflix performs protocol translation in their API gateway, but does it follow the SEDP principle in that way?

Comment: The important principle in SOA and Microservices is to reduce coupling, and avoid synchronous communication for state changes, for that aspect messaging can help achieve asynchronous durable communications... What tools you use are not the point really... Make sense?

Comment: I wanted to understand which component within MSA can be used to handle req/resp transformation. As per most write-ups in web, it is the API Gateway layer and not ESB. Just-in-case, somebody is using this layer to perform the same in MSA, are they violating SEDP principle?

Comment: It depends on the context, Messaging is not a silver bullet, and some scenarios you will need to use synchronous communication (for many reasons like business flows, development constraints, existing code and architecture...)  I see no reason why you shouldn't use a mix of messaging and synchronous communication, just be aware of the the coupling aspects you are introducing, and have a mitigation plan in place to transition if you need to...